# Adminer denied acces for user

Tags: mysql, permissions

sorry about my English, my knowledge about server is very small...

I have on my computer to install Mysql, Adminer, php-7.3 and Apache2. I to try a data bank to build, but to come to this warning,

> Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' to database 'mela'

**mela** is the new data bank which I to try to build, **me** is my username on 
Adminer.
When login on Mysql with `sudo mysql -u root`,
in `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;` I to come this,

```
SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
    +------------------+-----------+
    | User             | Host      |
    +------------------+-----------+
    | root             | %         |
    | me               | localhost |
    | mysql.infoschema | localhost |
    | mysql.session    | localhost |
    | mysql.sys        | localhost |
    +------------------+-----------+
```

With `sudo sudo journalctl -xe` to come,

> pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

and with `sudo systemctl -l status apache2.service`

> Jan 31 17:24:00 debian systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8IyJ.png): Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
>   Jan 31 17:24:00 debian systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8IyJ.png): Started The Apache HTTP Server.

With `sudo systemctl status mysql` to come this image,
[The image to show how started mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8IyJ.png)

with `Show grants;` to come this image
[what to come with this command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xran8.png)

Can Please anyone explains me with easy words, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a new installation of **Mysql** and login as **root**, now can open a data bank on **Adminer**..., I to say my steps..., I am with Debian.

**1 -** Stopping **Apache2**

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2.service
```

**2** - Remove all from **Mysql** on my computer

**CAUTION: this may remove a bunch of other packages that any link to MySQL, read carefully what will be removed.**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge *mysql\*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

**3 -** Because I delele all from **MySQL**, now install they...

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

**4 -** Also, install **Mysqli**, because I have **php7.3** on my computer, I install **Mysql** with **php7.3**.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysqli
```

**5 -** Sometimes and I don know why..later to installed **Mysql**, to come this warning,

> Connect Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

and as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53881212/11523795) to say, B*y default and for some reason, mysql 8 default plugin is auth_socket. Applications will most times expect to log in to your database using a* **password**. 
I do it, I login to **Mysql**, I give the **root password** which I wrote on my installation...

```
~$ mysql -u root -p
```

and write the command which him to say,

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password';
```

**6 -** Restart **Mysql**,

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

**7 -** Restart **Apache2**

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

**8 -** On **Adminer** login window, login as root, and how the window to show, I can build the **mela** data bank...
[window to show my mela data bank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9dnX.png)

@Abhijith, Thanks for your Answer, I wish your a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests the user "me" does not have permission on the database "mela"

To confirm this run the below command as the mysql user "me"

Show grants;

If the user has permission on the database it will be shown

Comment: thanks for your answer, I update my question and say was to come with this command..

Comment: Hello @dsaj34v you should run the command "show grants;" as the mysql user "me"